# How to implement choose user type in Symfony2 Forms?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

How to implement choose user type in Symfony2 Forms?

I want to create in form filed called user. And be able to choose user from DB (via Doctrine) with autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

1)You have to add in your form builder :

- a field text widget, unmapped  (will contain the text of the user type)
- a hidden field, unmapped (will contain the id of the use type)

2)Use the javascript library you want (i.e bootstrap typeahead is a good one).

3)Then, the javascript trigger an ajax method pointing on a action on your controller. This action return a list of user type (most likely encoded in json format)

4) Once the form is submited, in the update/create action of yours, find the entity corresponding to the hidden id submited, and link it to the entity

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for integration select2. check [this](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/select2/ajax.md) out